# AWS AppSync simple graphql resolver in Dynamo DB not working and it's driving me crazy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a very simple graphQL resolver I am trying to get working and for whatever reason it isn't and keeps returning null even though I have set a GSI on username which is what I am trying to query by.

**GraphQL schema:**

```
type Query {
    getUsersDevByUsername(username: String!): UsersDev
}

type UsersDev {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    group: Int
    hasProfile: Boolean
    currentSkill: Int
    highestSkill: Int
}
```

**GraphQL resolver on query:**

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "username-index",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "username = :username",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":username" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.username)
        }
    }
}
```

**Query I am trying to run:**

```
query test {
  getUsersDevByUsername(username:"testUser"){
    id
    username
    group
    currentSkill
    highestSkill

  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUsersDevByUsername": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getUsersDevByUsername",
        "id"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'ID' within parent 'UsersDev' (/getUsersDevByUsername/id)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "getUsersDevByUsername",
        "username"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'UsersDev' (/getUsersDevByUsername/username)"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I included the index I am using in the resolver and am following the example given in the resolver notes.  This is such a simple query and I don't understand why all this complexity is needed. The amount of time spent trying to configure ridiculously easy queries that would take literally 5 seconds to write in SQL is really turning me off to this. It's supposed to be "so awesome" but the boilerplate that is required to get it working is comical.

Can someone **PLEASE** help me get this working so I can actually work on something productive rather than why a simple query isn't working?

EDIT:

SO I finally got this working.  Needed to change the result from:

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

to:

```
#if($ctx.result.items.size()>0)
$util.toJson($ctx.result.items[0])
#else
null
#end)
```

which makes no sense since the AWS example with getting it by id uses the first one, but whatever, at least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running a query the response will have the following structure:

```
{
    items = [ ... ],
    nextToken = "a pagination token",
    scannedCount = 10
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query

In your response mapping template you want to handle that result:

- either by just returning *ctx.result.items*
- or, like in your case, if the fields are marked required and can't be null you need to handle the null case